# Duplicate objects randomly in a delimited zone

Tags: modifiers, objects, transforms

Is there a tool (a module or a easy method) to duplicate an object **many times**, **randomly** in **delimited zone** (the inside of a sphere for example) ?

Rather like the airbrush tool in a raster graphic editor (illustrated below), but instead of drawing dots, it would duplicate a preselected object :

[image]

---

*Note : I don't wish to use particles systems to duplicate objects (I need to keep control on positions)*

Comment: There's the *randomize transform* operator.. It doesn't support distributions inside arbitrary shapes, but it can be used to spread out objects in a random fashion (and optionally scale and rotate them). To distribute objects inside an arbitrary shape you'll need to use a particle system. You can always convert the particle system to real objects later in order to fine-tune their positions..

Comment: I was not aware of this functionality. Converting a particle system to real objects seem to make exactly what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6358/599) for details on how to setup a particle system for distributing objects inside a shape.

Once you've done that, you can convert a particle system to real objects with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> or the *convert* button in the modifiers panel:

[image]

Note that **this won't remove the particle system**, so remember to delete it if you are done with it.

[image]