# How can I make my particles freeze in time and convert them into a Mesh?

Tags: particles, physics

I made a particle system but now i want to extract the particles as a Mesh, or just froze the particles in time, for render time, is this possible?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28533/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5213/599

Comment: Note that you can also use a particle system which doesn't have physics to begin with, e.g. hair or an emitter with *None* as the physics type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Find the frame most suited to your goal with the particle system.
- Press the Convert button of the particle system modifier, you will have duplicates.  Make a selection of only the emitted particles. Do not include the original particle system mesh.
- Join the Meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>