# Deleting object generated from particle system

Tags: particles

I followed a tutorial online on using particle system to generate lots of buildings on top of a plane and I was supposed to press <kbd>B</kbd> to select some area of the plane to delete a row of buildings.

However, that only deleted the portion of the plane underneath and not the buildings. When I press <kbd>B</kbd> in Edit mode, I am not able to select and highlight the buildings, only the plane underneath get selected.

Can someone please help? (I am a beginner)

I tried uploading the .blend file here but unfortunately it is not processing the upload.
Thanks in advance.

This is my file [image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial ? The particles won't be accessible for selection unless you convert them to meshes like [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-can-i-convert-a-hair-particle-system-into-3d-editable-objects) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31680/how-can-i-make-my-particles-freeze-in-time-and-convert-them-into-a-mesh)

Comment: This is the youtube link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCEN0qQOsIA (around 30:10). Doesn't seem like any conversion was done in the video . I have also attached my file above. Thanks

Comment: The only thing Andrew is doing in that moment is selecting that plane underneath, just like you did, and deletes vertices of that plane. He makes roads in that way. You won't be able to select *buildings* themselves as they don't actually exist yet as a anything selectable. Another way could be to [Vertex Paint](https://www.blender.org/manual/painting_sculpting/painting/vertex_paint/introduction.html) plane and add created vertex group in Particles settings > Vertex Groups.